# Back button PhoneGap Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, cordova, back-button

While certifiying my Phonegap App for Windows Phone 7 I was told that the back-button doesn't work the way it should. My application only has one page, so here it's not a problem but it is possible to display a menu using javascript.

When this menu is open, the back-button is supposed to close the menu instead of exiting the application. Does anyone have an idea on how I could easily catch the event of a click on the back-button in order to check if the menu is open and then close it or completely exit the application if it isn't?

I tried `document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);` but apparently this does not work for Windows Phone 7!

Thanks a lot

Comment: From what I've seen, WP7/7.5's WebView is plain terrible to base any app-like functionality on, so you might be in for a lot of trouble here. As far as I know, the sandboxed JS can't interact with OS features at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [back button function for phonegap windows phone 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341835/back-button-function-for-phonegap-windows-phone-7)

Comment: @esko the op is asking about phonegap, which does exactly that, exposes native phone functions to your JavaScript code

Comment: @ColinE I know what he's talking about, my point is that as far as I know, WP7 as a platform won't allow PhoneGap to do any system level functions so that it could be bound all the way to JavaScript running in sandboxed browser inside thin wrapper application. Sure, I might be wrong so this might be completely invalid.

Comment: @esko I think you are right and wrong! You cannot access system level functions from the wp7 browser, but this is no different from android and iOS. Technologies like PhoneGap fill this ... Erm ... Gap!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WP7 PhoneGap definitely supports the back button. You can download a working example from my blog here:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/11/handling-the-back-stack-in-windows-phone-7-phonegap-applications/

Make sure you handle the deviceready event first.

Comment: You were right, I hade some simple coding errors that prevented the use of this functionality. Now it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you use the native Silverlight.

#### XMAL

```
BackKeyPress="PageBackKeyPress"
```

#### Code-Behind

```
private void PageBackKeyPress(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // DO NOT CLOSE
    if (Something)
        e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Comment: Using native Silverlight will make the application non portable. I am assuming phonegap is being used for cross platform coding.

Comment: Yea well PhoneGap (as well as others that do that same thing) are not 100% portable. Your going to find kinks that work one way on one device and another way on another device. I really recommend learning the native OS language.

Comment: native vs. Cross platform is a topic fora different stack overflow question. To answer the op, yes, phinegap does support the back button for wp7 and android. They must have just made some simple error.

Answer (score -3):

I have the same problem. When you write

> document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

That will block the the default backbutton handler. So you may need to do so tricks in the phonegap code. It's not the best way, but it's quite easy though. Check out this one:
http://blog.projectdebug.com/?p=6